# How to access props from any screen using react navigation 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i wanna ask question. Im new to react and dont know how to use useNavigation on react component. How to access the props in Navigation on the third screen, so it can go to details of the feeds (screen 4), espcially using react navigation 5.

App.js

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Berita" component={BeritaScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Tournament" component={TournamentScreen} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Home.js

```
....
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#eee',marginTop:20,marginBottom:10}}></View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 100 }}>
            <Text style={{ width: 160, textTransform: 'uppercase', fontFamily: 'montserrat_bold', letterSpacing: -1, margin: 15, fontSize: 17 }}>Berita Pilihan</Text>
            <View style={{ width: 240, margin: 20, marginLeft: -30, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <Image source={require('../assets/icon/stripes.png')} style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }} imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'repeat' }} />
            </View>
          </View>
        <Feeds />
      </Content>
      </Container>
```

Feeds.js

```
renderRow = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        this.state.isLoading
        ?
        <View style={{flex:1, alignItem:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="Large" color="#222" animating/>
        </View>
        :
        <List style={{}}>
            <ListItem 
            onPress={() =>  this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen')}
            thumbnail thumbnail style={{ marginTop:5,marginBottom: 5, height: 90 }}>
                <Left style={{ width: 100 }}>
                    <Thumbnail style={{ flex: 1, borderRadius: 4, width: '100%', height: 80 }} square source={{ uri: item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url }} />
                </Left>
                <Body style={{}}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{item._embedded['wp:term'][0][0].name}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize:15, fontFamily: "montserrat_bold", letterSpacing: -.5 }} >{item.title.rendered} </Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:11,marginTop:5}}>{item._embedded.author[0].name}</Text>
                </Body>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    );
}

render() {

    let { dataSource, isLoading } = this.state
    return (

        <>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
            onRefresh={this.fetchData}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={this.renderRow}
        />
        </>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**passing props**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
            itemId: 86,
            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
          });
```

**accessing the props in the next screen**

```
const { itemId,otherParam } = this.props.route.params;
console.log(itemId);
console.log(otherParam);
```